# Error injecting a mock dependency in dagger2

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm just playing around trying to get to know Dagger2 a bit better.  I found a simple example on the web where a `Bar` depends on a `BarDatabase`:

```
    public class Bar {
       // Bar depends on BarDatabase
       private BarDatabase db;

       @Inject
       public Bar(BarDatabase db) {
          this.db = db;
       }

       public BarDatabase getBar() { return db; }

       public Cocktail getCocktail(String name) {
          String row = db.getCocktail(name);
          return new Cocktail(row);
       }
    }
```

Dagger works just peachy with the following Module and Component:

```
    package com.example.eflatt.di.barcomponent;
    import com.example.eflatt.di.Bar;
    import com.example.eflatt.di.module.BarModule;
    import com.example.eflatt.di.testmodule.TestBarModule;
    import javax.inject.Singleton;
    import dagger.Component;

     /**
      * Created by eflatt on 4/26/16.
      */
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = {BarModule.class, TestBarModule.class})
    public interface BarComponent {
        public Bar provideBar();
    }

    package com.example.eflatt.di.module;

    import com.example.eflatt.di.Bar;
    import com.example.eflatt.di.BarDatabase;
    import com.example.eflatt.di.MockBarDatabase;
    import javax.inject.Singleton;
    import dagger.Module;
    import dagger.Provides;

    /**
     * Created by eflatt on 4/26/16.
     */
    @Module
    public class BarModule {
       @Provides @Singleton
       public Bar provideBar () {
       return new Bar(new BarDatabase());
    }
 }
```

But I wanted to try injecting a MockBarDatabase() in my unittest, which is when things went off the rails.

Question 1:  I decided to write a TestBarModule which new'd a MockBarDatabase() in the provideBar method (separate file called TestBarModule) - is this the wrong technique?

```
    @Module
    public class TestBarModule {
      @Provides @Singleton
      public Bar provideBar () {
          return new Bar(new MockBarDatabase());
      }
    }
```

Question 2:  If writing a separate Module to handle the Mock case *is* the right thing to do (I'm guessing it's not), then how do I deal with the fact that my IDE tells me:

> Error:(15, 16) error: com.example.eflatt.di.Bar is bound multiple times:
>   @Provides @Singleton com.example.eflatt.di.Bar com.example.eflatt.di.module.BarModule.provideBar()
>   @Provides @Singleton com.example.eflatt.di.Bar com.example.eflatt.di.testmodule.TestBarModule.provideBar()

Answer (score 0):

> is this the wrong technique?

Yes.

What you do is, you configure everything to use constructor injection

```
@Inject
public Bar(BarDatabase db) {
   this.db = db;
}
```

then you decide to still provide it yourself and on top of that not to make use of the dagger framework and handle things yourself

```
@Provides @Singleton
public Bar provideBar () {
    // MockBarDatabase isn't supplied by dagger but by you.
    return new Bar(new MockBarDatabase());
}
```

### Improvements

On the very least you should provide every dependency on its own. You will then also see that its a whole lot easier to switch single objects for mock objects

```
// this would be a 'righter' way to do it
@Provides @Singleton
public Bar provideBar (MockBarDatabase db) {
    return new Bar(db);
}
```

`MockBarDatabase` would have to be provided from a different `@Provides` method in the sample above. But as mentioned earlier, you *already configured everything for constructor injection*. So use it. You could just go ahead and omit any `new` calls:

```
// dagger will create the object for you!
@Provides @Singleton
public Bar provideBar (Bar bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

This is also how you would implement an interface. Or just make full use of the constructor injection and *don't* specify your own method in your module. Now in your case if you really want your bar to be singleton, you'd have to adapt your class:

```
@Singleton
public class Bar {
    @Inject Bar(Db db) {/**/}
    // ...
}
```

And yes, your module would then just need to provide the `BarDatabase`, if it cannot be also constructor injected.

Components can just create objects if they have an annotated constructor *and their dependencies can also be created* (constructor injection) *or provided* (those `@Provide` and `@Modules`). So make use of that, and only use modules if you can not use constructor injection or need Qualifiers or additional setup.

---

I don't know how you create this error, but I believe you tried adding a second module providing the mock object to the same component?

If you want to mock modules try subclassing the module and *overriding* the method to provide the object.

There are a lot of good tutorials and samples out there on dagger 2 and I highly recommend you digging into those.

Comment: Thanks for the snippets.  Truth is, my initial stab at this I didn't explicitly new the deps as I had here, it's just that I've found (in contrast to you) few good tutorials.  Tons for guice, tons that go on about DI and why to use it w/ a small mention of dagger on the backend, but a real step by step tutorial - not so lucky (so I just started screwing around w/ a trivial example, and then went and read the gen'd code).  So if you have any one you like in particular, I'd love it.  Thanks again for the snippets and taking a look, I appreciate it.

Comment: @EricFlatt [This one](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/) was the most informative for me, but you should start by just carefully reading the [User Guide](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html) if you didn't do so already, also the actual javadoc also explains most things in detail